# tree reduction technique that adds siblings to a node on each visit

Tags: javascript, graph

Say I have a tree that looks like:

[image]

I want to walk the tree and perform some operation on each node, returning the modified tree. However, for some nodes (based on some condition), the operation performed needs to generate additional siblings, i.e.:

[image]

So for the above example, when the program is currently visiting node `F` the operation performed needs to return not only the modified `F` node, but another `F2` node, and that `F2` node will then be visited recursively by the program.

I am having trouble figuring out how to add siblings while walking the tree.

Originally I thought to basically re-construct the parent node with the appropriate amount of siblings but I'm probably approaching this incorrectly altogether.

```
const walk = (node, parent) => {
  // as an example, this is where I need to generate siblings
  const nextSiblings = node.value === 'F' ? [node, {value: 'F2'}] : [node]
  const nextParent = parent ? node : {...parent, childNodes: nextSiblings}
  const childNodes = nextParent.childNodes.map(child => walk(child, node))
  return { ...nextParent, childNodes }
}

describe('walk', () => {
  it('should add F2 node', () => {
    // not same as diagram, but same concept
    const tree = {
      value: 'A',
      childNodes: [{value: 'F'}, {value: 'C'}]
    }
    assert.strictEqual(
      walk(tree),
      `
        {
          value: 'A',
          childNodes: [{value: 'F'}, {value: 'F2'}, {value: 'C'}]
        }
      `
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you need to be able to add a sibling to the element you are working on? Have you tried the parentNode property in combination with the appendChild method? a.e.: node.parentNode.appendChild(siblingNode)

Comment: this is dom agnostic @zfrisch